# Convertible Bond Price change estimation using Delta/Gamma

Tags: convertible-bond

The holder of a convertible bond is effectively long an American call option on
the underlying shares.

given the delta and gamma, and underlying stock price change, what is the best way to estimate the CB price change?

example:
delta 80%
gamma 0.4
underlying stock price: 100
underlying stock price shock: -25%
current CB price: 120
CB price with if underlying equity is down by 25% ?

it appears that linear approximation would give the below result:

120*80% * (-25%) + 0.5 * 120 * 0.4 * 25% * 25% = -22.5

so the new CB price under the shock scenario would be 120-22.5 = 97.5

but this new CB price is too low comparing to what happens in real world or using Bloomberg OVCV calculator.
I guess it's because of the linear approximation doesn't work if the equity shock is too large.

any one has any good ideas to estimate the CB price/PNL change in this case?

Comment: You should apply the approximation to the price of the option and not the full price of the convertible bond. If the convertible bond is very much in the money in your example then it probably works OK for large increase in price but won't work for large decreases, because at some point the option value will be low and the bond value will start taking effect. I would try and estimate the MV change for the option and bond separately and check which one is biting to prevent the overestimation of the shock you show in the question.